# How to use a camera in Corona Simulator?

Tags: camera, lua, simulator, coronasdk

I'm wondering how to use a camera in Corona Simulator. I want to test my app (which requires a camera) out on the simulator but i don't know how to enable usage for a camera. Is there anyway to set up my webcam to act as the simulators camera? I just want to know if this is possible or would I just have to put my app onto a device to test it with a camera.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the device camera or photo library you would call something like:

```
media.show( mediaSource, listener [, filetable] )
```

In order to test this, you'd have to load the app on your phone. Corona doesn't allow you to use a webcam for the simulator. For more information check out the Corona Docs @ http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/media/show.html